# How are there some Victor airways that exceed the service area of the VORs they are identified by?

Tags: faa-regulations, range, vor, ifr-navigation

As you can see [here](http://skyvector.com/?ll=31.51580564437983,-82.16400146836585&chart=302&zoom=6&plan=V.K7.CRG:V.K7.DBN), V267 has a length of 149nm, is defined by the Craig VOR (CRG) and the Dublin VOR (DBN) and has a MEA of 3000. [According to the AIM](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim/aim0101.html#CwA1d6ROBE), the Service volumes of VORs never reach more then 40nm underneath 14,500ft.

Yes, the Craig VOR or rather VORTAC is described to have the Standart High Altitude Service Volume in the A/FD, but at the MEA, which should also guarantee reception of the navaids in use, the range is still only 40nm. A route at that altitude between those two navaids should only be <80nm, so how can it be 149nm?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It says it [right there on the page where the service volumes are described in the AIM](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim/aim0101.html#ncG212JACK):

> 1-1-8. Navigational Aid (NAVAID) Service Volumes
>
> c. Standard Service Volume **limitations do not apply to published IFR
>   routes** or procedures.

So V267 has been flown at the MEA by an FAA plane, and it obviously met the signal accuracy requirements to be usable at the distances charted.

Comment: So that implies that the Service Volumes are just areas of guaranteed coverage while you might be still able to receive a signal out of them?

Comment: @Maverick283 Correct, the signal is normally usable further out than the guaranteed service volume, but as you might imagine, it is not guaranteed.

Comment: and the limitations are real. These are for DBN: 
`HIWAS BROADCAST.
VOR PORTION UNUSABLE 215-285 BYD 10NM BLO 3,500 FT.
VOR PORTION UNUSABLE 001-139 BYD 33 NM ALL ALT.
VOR PORTION UNUSABLE 001-139 BLO 5,000 FT AL DIST.
`